# Count using useState doesnt update state until question 6 even when answered correctly react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

im trying to create a quiz app in react using hooks. i want the answers to be clickable and once clicked the user will then move onto the next question. My problem is that, the score state isnt updating until question 6! i am making an API call to get the questions and answers using useEffect. i know that useState is asynchronous and thats why state doesnt update straight away, its just even if i answer the first 6 questions correctly, after question 6 the score is still showing 1. Does anyone have a way around this?

My API call using useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("https://my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com/api/newq").then((res) => {
      const allQuestions = res.data;
      setResult([allQuestions]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [setResult]);
```

My Quiz component:

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useContext,
  useEffect
} from "react";

import {
  QuizContext
} from "../Helpers/context";

const MainQuiz = () => {
  const {
    score,
    setScore,
    result
  } = useContext(QuizContext);

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
  const [optionChosen, setOptionChosen] = useState("");
  console.log(optionChosen);
  console.log(result);

  const nextQuestion = (correctAnswer) => {
    if (optionChosen === correctAnswer) {
      setScore((score) => score + 1);
    }
    setCurrentQuestion((currentQuestion) => currentQuestion + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("score updated", score);
  }, [score]);
  return ( <
    div className = "quiz" > {
      result.map((question, index) => {
        if (currentQuestion < question.allQuiz.length) {
          return ( <
            h3 key = {
              index
            } > {
              question.allQuiz[currentQuestion].q_prompt
            } < /h3>
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    } <
    div className = "answer__container" > {
      result.map((answers, index) => {
        if (currentQuestion < answers.allQuiz.length) {
          return ( <
            div className = "answer__options" > {
              " "
            } <
            button className = "question__choices"
            onClick = {
              () => {
                setOptionChosen("a");
                nextQuestion(
                  result[0].allQuiz[currentQuestion].q_correctAnswer
                );
              }
            } >
            {
              answers.allQuiz[currentQuestion].a
            } <
            /button> <
            button className = "question__choices"
            onClick = {
              () => {
                setOptionChosen("b");
                nextQuestion(
                  result[0].allQuiz[currentQuestion].q_correctAnswer
                );
              }
            } >
            {
              answers.allQuiz[currentQuestion].b
            } <
            /button> <
            button className = "question__choices"
            onClick = {
              () => {
                setOptionChosen("c");
                nextQuestion(
                  result[0].allQuiz[currentQuestion].q_correctAnswer
                );
              }
            } >
            {
              answers.allQuiz[currentQuestion].c
            } <
            /button> <
            button className = "question__choices"
            onClick = {
              () => {
                setOptionChosen("d");
                nextQuestion(
                  result[0].allQuiz[currentQuestion].q_correctAnswer
                );
              }
            } >
            {
              answers.allQuiz[currentQuestion].d
            } <
            /button> <
            /div>
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    } <
    /div> <
    span > {
      score
    } < /span> <
    /div>
  );
};

export default MainQuiz;
```

Comment: There are too many unknowns in this snippet to know what the issue might be. As a first point in debugging, have you tried: a) putting breakpoints inside `nextQuestion` to check if the `correctAnswer` and `optionChosen` are as you expect? b) inspecting your API response to see if it has the data in the shape you expect? (b) is likely only relevant if `correctAnswer` is not what you expect - particularly if it is `undefined` So a) is definitely the starting point in my opinion.)

Comment: ahh so yes the optionChosen is one behind, so when you click the first question it registers it as an empty string

Comment: Also, a working example (maybe in codesandbox.io) to demo the issue would really help people help you.

Comment: @James thanks for checking this - see what I mean about the best starting point for debugging? Anyway I apologise because I should have spotted this issue. It's due to React state updates being asynchronous - so when you `setOptionChosen(something)`, `optionChosen` doesn't get the value you've set until the next render, which is after you've called `nextQuestion`. The easy fix here is I think to keep `optionChosen` out of state entirely - you don't appear to need it for rendering or anything else, so just pass it as an additional argument to `nextQuestion`.

Comment: sure - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-moon-cmvbc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Robin Zigmond Thanks, i will give this a try